# How to apply patterns to curved triangle

Tags: asymptote, fill

I am trying to apply patterns to curved triangles, but it is not working properly,it seems to be more tricky than I expected, though. This is the code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{asy}[width=\textwidth]

settings.render=0;
settings.prc=false;
import three;
import graph3;
import grid3;
currentprojection=obliqueX;

pen thickblack = black+0.75;
real axislength = 1.0;
draw(L=Label("$x$", position=Relative(1.1), align=SW), O--axislength*X,thickblack, Arrow3); 
draw(L=Label("$y$", position=Relative(1.1), align=E), O--axislength*Y,thickblack, Arrow3); 
draw(L=Label("$z$", position=Relative(1.1), align=N), O--axislength*Z,thickblack, Arrow3); 

real a=0.5;

label("$a$", (a,0,0), align=NW);
label("$a$", (0,a,0), align=NE);
label("$a$", (0,0,a), align=NW);

draw(O--expi(pi/2,pi/4),black+0.25);
draw(arc(c=O, a*Y, a*Z), blue);
draw(arc(c=O, a*X, a*Z), red);

dot((a,a,0)); 

draw((0,a,0)--(a,a,0),blue);
draw((a,a,0)--(a,0,0),red);
draw((0,0,a)--(0,0.9,a),red);
draw((a,0,0)--(a,0.9,0),red);
draw(arc(c=(0,0.8,0),(a,0.8,0), (0,0.8,a)), red);

draw((a,a,0)--(0.9,a,0),blue);
draw((0,0,a)--(0.9,0,a),blue);

triple f(real t) {
    return (a*cos(t),a*cos(t),a*sin(t));
}

path3 ellarc = graph(f, 0, pi/2, operator ..,n=101); 
path3 ellarcp = graph(f,  pi/2,0, operator ..,n=101); 
path3 t1=((0,0,0) -- (0,a,0) -- (a,a,0) -- cycle);
surface s1=surface(t1);
draw(s1,red+opacity(.6),light=nolight);

path3 t2=((0,0,0) -- (a,0,0) -- (a,a,0) -- cycle);
surface s2=surface(t2);
draw(s2,blue+opacity(.6),light=nolight);

path3 ec1 = ( arc(c=O, a*Y, a*Z) -- (ellarcp) -- cycle); 
surface sec1=surface(ec1); 
draw(sec1,magenta+opacity(.5),light=nolight); 

path3 ec2 = ( (ellarc) .. arc(c=O, a*Z, a*X)-- cycle); 
surface sec2=surface(ec2); 
draw(sec2,yellow+opacity(.5),light=nolight);

draw(ellarc,black+1.3);


\end{asy}
\end{center}
```

I do not know what is going on. If I comment out "path3 ec1" or "path3 ec2" line in this code, the images attached show the issue for each curved triangle. Sorry if this is so basic, I am naive to asymptote.[image: Fig000][image: Fig001][image: Fig002][image: Fig003]

Comment: The `surface(path3)` path looks attractive but in practice it rarely does what you want for a non-planar surface. You need to use a more sophisticated way of constructing a surface. For these particular examples, I recommend using a surface of revolution.

Comment: Great! I will try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, it is sufficient to construct the parametrized surface. Please find the code

```
//settings.render=0;
//settings.prc=false;
import three;
import graph3;
import grid3;
currentprojection=obliqueX;

size3(10cm);

pen thickblack = black+0.75;
real axislength = 1.0;
draw(L=Label("$x$", position=Relative(1.1), align=SW), O--axislength*X,thickblack, Arrow3); 
draw(L=Label("$y$", position=Relative(1.1), align=E), O--axislength*Y,thickblack, Arrow3); 
draw(L=Label("$z$", position=Relative(1.1), align=N), O--axislength*Z,thickblack, Arrow3); 

real a=0.5;

label("$a$", (a,0,0), align=NW);
label("$a$", (0,a,0), align=NE);
label("$a$", (0,0,a), align=NW);

draw(O--expi(pi/2,pi/4),black+0.25);
draw(arc(c=O, a*Y, a*Z), blue);
draw(arc(c=O, a*X, a*Z), red);

dot((a,a,0)); 

draw((0,a,0)--(a,a,0),blue);
draw((a,a,0)--(a,0,0),red);
draw((0,0,a)--(0,0.9,a),red);
draw((a,0,0)--(a,0.9,0),red);
draw(arc(c=(0,0.8,0),(a,0.8,0), (0,0.8,a)), red);

draw((a,a,0)--(0.9,a,0),blue);
draw((0,0,a)--(0.9,0,a),blue);

triple f(real t) {
    return (a*cos(t),a*cos(t),a*sin(t));
}

path3 ellarc = graph(f, 0, pi/2, operator ..,n=101); 
path3 ellarcp = graph(f,  pi/2,0, operator ..,n=101); 
path3 t1=((0,0,0) -- (0,a,0) -- (a,a,0) -- cycle);
surface s1=surface(t1);
draw(s1,red+opacity(.6),light=nolight);

path3 t2=((0,0,0) -- (a,0,0) -- (a,a,0) -- cycle);
surface s2=surface(t2);
draw(s2,blue+opacity(.6),light=nolight);

triple g( pair z)
{
    return (z.y*a*cos(z.x),a*cos(z.x),a*sin(z.x));

}
//path3 ec1 = ( arc(c=O, a*Y, a*Z) -- (ellarcp) -- cycle); 
//surface sec1=surface(ec1);
draw(surface(g,(0,0),(pi/2,1),Spline),magenta+opacity(.5)+4bp,light=nolight); 


triple h( pair z)
{
    return (a*cos(z.x),z.y*a*cos(z.x),a*sin(z.x));

}
//path3 ec2 = ( (ellarc) .. arc(c=O, a*Z, a*X)-- cycle); 
//surface sec2=surface(ec2); 
draw(surface(h,(0,0),(pi/2,1),Spline),yellow+opacity(.5),light=nolight);

draw(ellarc,black+1.3);
```

Since I have some transparency problem with `render=0` and since with `render=0` the 3D is very limited, I use the true 3D GL render.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.